# Trouble with font map when moving from Texlive 2017 to Texlive 2020

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

In my free physics book, the cls file contains a line to define fmy as standard sans-serif font:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fmy}
```

which worked well for many years. Today I updated from TexLive2017 to TeXLive 2020.

The result is that dvips bombs - no .ps file is produced:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 0+360/600 --dpi 360 fmyr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fmyr8r.
mktexpk: perhaps fmyr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
dvips: Font fmyr8r not found; using cmr10

</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: ! invalid char 150 from font fmyr8r
```

Ok, this is a **font map** issue. Since I have no idea any more (after 10 years) where the map for the fonts is, how can I find out?

All the .fd files are in my home directory. The commands

```
sudo -H mktexlsr
sudo -H updmap-sys
```

had no effect. The problem persists. The page http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html did not help.

Comment: The warning is harmless and not causing dvips to bomp. dvips bombs as the font is not found. You didn't activate the map file of the font.

Comment: Ok, I did not do that for many years - I have to find out how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Well look in your texlive 2017. You did install the font there. map-files are normally somewhere in fonts/map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experts friends help me in the meantime.

There were two options. The general one:

```
sudo -H updmap-user --enable Map=MinionPro.map
sudo -H updmap-user --enable Map=minionmath-ps.map
sudo -H updmap-user --enable Map=springer.map
```

(Here is a comment to the people who wrote the TexLive installer: this should not be necessary when reinstalling Tex...)

The special one: use dvips with maps:

```
dvips -R -Poutline -G0 -j0 -u +MinionPro.map -u +springer.map -u +minionmath-ps.map ...
```